# How Can i connect workbench Sql in JMeter5.0

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, database-performance

I have tried with JDBC connecter but i got the error like

Cannot load JDBC driver class **'com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver'**

Answer (score 0):

1. Take the driver [from MS site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/download-microsoft-jdbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) (choose the version that fits your set up yourself).
2. Drop the jar file with a driver to the `lib` folder in your JMeter home dir.
3. Restart JMeter & proceed.

P.S. I would strongly suggest you to check out documentation next time - it's all there already:

> Must be in JMeter's classpath - easiest to copy .jar file into
>   JMeter's /lib directory

Comment: Thanks, @Yuri G, Sorry, But I have tried a lot with this thing but still, it is not connected to the database. MY JMETER version is 5.0. and want to connect with Workbench GUI My Sql. please help me... Which Version of JDBC driver compatible with JMeter 5.0

Comment: That's not about JMeter compatibility. It would take any. That's YOUR database. Check its version out, lookup at the page I've mentioned for the driver that suites this version, go for it.